# Regular expression domain will not get the .uk of a domain co.uk

Tags: regex

With group 1 I get the name of the domain. But group 2 will not get the `UK` of the domain

Here is the code in regex:
https://regex101.com/r/Svg7KY/1

```
First try:   /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^.]+)((?:[.,]\w+))/gm
Second try: /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^.]+)([,.](?=[^.,]*$)\w+)/gm
```

> ```
> nu.co.uk
> www.nu.co.uk
> http://www.nu.co.uk
> https://www.nu.co.uk
> ```

Comment: Try `^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^.]+)([.,]\w+)+` https://regex101.com/r/rZw5A9/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks that did the job :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture `uk` in the second capturing group you could repeat 0 or more times matching a dot followed by 1+ word characters.

Then match a dot and capture the last word characters in group 1

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^.]+)(?:[.,]\w+)*\.(\w+)
```

About the last part `(?:[.,]\w+)*\.(\w+)`

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[.,]\w+` Match a dot or comma and 1+ word chars
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `\.` Match a dot
- `(\w+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WKKpr6/1)

Comment: thx but the last dot should not be in there.. how to remove it?

Comment: @ftft32 Like this https://regex101.com/r/mNqo00/1 ? You can repeat 0 or more times a word character preceded by a dot and match a dot and capture the last word characters in the group.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the regex in the link you provided. The reason it isn't matching the "uk" is because those examples have more `\.\w+` occurrences than the others. You could just add a quantifier to that last group to make it work:

`^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^.]+)((?:[.,]\w+)){1,2}`

Also, is the comma needed in the last group's character class? If not, you could simplify the regex to:

`^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:\w+)(?:\.\w+)+`